# Retrieve sequence of XML Elements from XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I have a sample xml as follows

```
<users>
  <user>
    <username>John</username>
    <password>password1</password>
    <id>1234</id>
  </user>
  <user>
    <username>Smith</username>
    <password>password2</password>
    <id>1234</id>
  </user>       
<users>
```

This XML file is loaded into XDocument object like this..

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Users.xml");
```

How can I retrieve values of password and id elements by passing username as a parameter to it where username is unique in c#.net 4.0

Comment: Well, the age old Stack Overflow question...what have you tried?

Comment: There is no id for username. If the username passed is John, then it should retrieve all the other elements with element name and value under that particular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code snippet (method) to extract the `password` from Xml `doc` by passing `UserName` as parameter:

```
public string GetUserPassword(string UserName)
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Users.xml");
    XmlNodeList _users = xDoc.SelectNodes("//users/user");
    string _pwd = null;
    foreach (XmlNode _node in _users)
    {
        if (_node.SelectSingleNode("username").InnerText == UserName)
        {
            _pwd = _node.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText;
            break;
        }
    }
    return _pwd;
}
```

And, similar one to get the `id`:

```
public string GetId(string UserName)
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Users.xml");
    XmlNodeList _users = xDoc.SelectNodes("//users/user");
    string _id = null;
    foreach (XmlNode _node in _users)
    {
        if (_node.SelectSingleNode("username").InnerText == UserName)
        {
            _id = _node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;
            break;
        }
    }
    return _id;
}
```

For performance optimization you can combine this two methods into one, so the Xml document will be loaded just once while method will return the array `string[] _pwdAndId`, where `_pwdAndId[0]` corresponds to the id and `_pwdAndId[1]` to password.

```
public string[] GetPasswordAndId(string UserName)
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Users.xml");
    XmlNodeList _users = xDoc.SelectNodes("//users/user");
    string[] _pwdAndId = new string[2];
    foreach (XmlNode _node in _users)
    {
        if (_node.SelectSingleNode("username").InnerText == UserName)
        {
            _pwdAndId[0] = _node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;
            _pwdAndId[1] = _node.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText;
            break;
        }
    }
    return _pwdAndId ;
}
```

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: dang was just about to post pretty much exact same answer!!

Comment: @clamchoda: great minds are thinking alike :). I upvote your comments. Best regards,